# Detect if interrupt 1 has happened before or after executing a certain instruction in TASM

Tags: assembly, interrupt, x86-16, tasm

I need to check if an interrupt (int 1) has occurred before executing the IMUL instruction.

I have this code fragment and now I need to check whether INT 1 was called before IMUL function or after and print some sort of messages after. This code was given as an example and now I need to supplement it.  It sets TF, which raises interrupt 3 after every instruction.

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data
PranNe  db "Not IMUL", 13, 10, "$"

.code
Start:
MOV ax, @data   
MOV ds, ax      

MOV ax, 0       
MOV es, ax      ;write 0 to es because the interrupt vector table is in the segment whose start address is 00000

PUSH    es:[4]
PUSH    es:[6]

MOV word ptr es:[4], offset ApdorokPertr    ;record the offset of the interrupt handling procedure from the start of the code segment in the interrupt vector table
MOV es:[6], cs              ;write the segment of the interrupt handling procedure into the interrupt vector table

PUSHF           
PUSHF           
POP ax          
OR ax, 0100h        ; TF=1
PUSH ax         
POPF            
NOP         
;*************************************************************
;This command will be handled by the interrupt handler
MOV al,00h
MOV cl,01h
IMUL cl
;*************************************************************

POPF            
;Since then TF was equal to 0, we knock down TF in this way
POP es:[6]
POP es:[4]

MOV ah, 4Ch     
MOV al, 0   
INT 21h     

PROC ApdorokPertr
;put register values ​​on the stack
PUSH    ax
PUSH    bx
PUSH    dx
PUSH    bp
PUSH    es
PUSH    ds

MOV ax, @data
MOV ds, ax

;In the DL register, we write the operation code of the command before which the INT was called
MOV bp, sp      
ADD bp, 12      
MOV bx, [bp]        
MOV es, [bp+2]      
MOV dl, [es:bx]     ;extract the first byte located at the return address - command OPK

;check if INT was called before the IMUL command here
MOV al, dl

;here I dont know how to check if its IMUL command or not
;if it is I need to display a warning and all information about the instruction: 
;address, code, mnemonic, operands.


;If INT was not called before the IMUL command, then we output a message
MOV ah, 9
MOV dx, offset PranNe
INT 21h
JMP endd

;reset the register values ​​and exit the interrupt handler
endd:
POP ds
POP es
POP bp
POP dx
POP bx
POP ax
IRET            

ApdorokPertr ENDP

END Start
```

I have to check it with IMUL's bulk code, but I have no idea how to do that... Can someone help me out?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, it seems that all you need to do is have some global flag variable, e.g. IntHandlerCalled: byte, that you set to zero before adding the trap flag. You set this to one from within the interrupt handler, and then check after the `idiv` instruction whether or not it was set. --- Remember to pay attention to the use of segments when accessing the flag variable.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thank you for your answer! But I've never worked with trap flags, or I didn't know I worked with them:/ Can you explain a little bit more or guide me how to use it please?

Comment: Sure - setting the trap flag, TF in your code, in the Flags register causes the CPU to go into a debug mode temporarily where it executes a single instruction and then triggers the interrupt while also clearing the flag. That's my recollection anyway but I've not coded DOS programs for over 20 years.

Comment: Your code sets TF, which raises a debug interrupt (like `int3`) after every instruction.  Are you sure `int 1` is what you're looking for?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_flag describes the exception as a "type-1 interrupt", but that's not talking about the interrupt number.

Comment: @PeterCordes No no I need to check if specifically INT 1 happens before IMUL or after, that's what my task requests for:/

Comment: Then don't mess around with TF, that's not useful, and it's weird that you have this complicated code doing that.  Just install a handler for `int 1` that sets a global variable, like 500-InternalServerError said.